# Can we use SVG icons outside those provided by SLDS?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have created an SVG Lightning component that takes 3 attributes, namely, "class","xlinkHref" and "areaHidden".

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="class" type="String" description="CSS classname for the SVG element" />
  <aura:attribute name="xlinkHref" type="String" description="SLDS icon path. Ex: /assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#download" />
  <aura:attribute name="ariaHidden" type="String" default="false" description="aria-hidden true or false. defaults to true" />
</aura:component>
```

The renderer.js given below does the ground-work to render the SVG icon provided through xlinkHref attribute.

```
({
  render: function(component, helper) {
    //grab attributes from the component markup
    var classname = component.get("v.class");
    var xlinkhref = component.get("v.xlinkHref");
    var ariaHidden = component.get("v.ariaHidden");

    //return an svg element w/ the attributes
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    svg.setAttribute('class', classname);
    svg.setAttribute('aria-hidden', ariaHidden);
    svg.innerHTML = '<use xlink:href="'+xlinkhref+'"></use>';
    return svg;
  }
})
```

Here is the example use case:

```
<c:svg class="slds-icon" xlinkHref="/resource/SLDS100/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#home" />
```

All this work fine, as long as I provide path to any icon within SLDS Sprite maps (Action, custom, standard, Utility). However, the list is not exhaustive. I'm looking for a "pause" icon and I couldn't find it in SLDS sprite maps.

I tried to use a pause SVG from [here](https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=pause), saved it under static resources and in the xlinkHref parameter I used "/resources/name_of_the_static_resource_for_pause_icon". The icon didn't turn up on the UI.

Can anyone point out what's wrong?

Comment: Yes of course - just point your svgurl to a different static resource.

Comment: I downloaded an SVG for 'pause' button (from https://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=pause) and added it to the static resource, then changed the svgurl to point to it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component markup put the SVG inside an CDATA container and surround it with DIV giving an aura:id.

```
<div aura:id="svg_content">
<![CDATA[
    <svg width="120px" height="120px" viewBox="0 0 120 120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <path d="M120,108 C120,114.6 114.6,120 108,120 L12,120 C5.4,120 0,114.6 0,108 L0,12 C0,5.4 5.4,0 12,0 L108,0 C114.6,0 120,5.4 120,12 L120,108 L120,108 Z" id="Shape" fill="#2A739E"/>
            <path d="M77.7383308,20 L61.1640113,20 L44.7300055,63.2000173 L56.0543288,63.2000173 L40,99.623291 L72.7458388,54.5871812 L60.907727,54.5871812 L77.7383308,20 Z" id="Path-1" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
]]>
</div>
```

Then in the renderer.js for the component, override the afterRender method:

```
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    var svg = component.find("svg_content");
    var value = svg.getElement().innerText;
    value = value.replace("<![CDATA[", "").replace("]]>", "");
    svg.getElement().innerHTML = value;        
}
```

This is a workaround that works for any SVGs outside of those provided by SLDS.