# lightning:icon pointing to SVG static resource has empty shadow root

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, static-resources, svg, shadow-dom

An working SVG icon stored in a public static resource `myicon_svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g id="requiredId"><path fill="#fff" d="m54.3 74.1c-2.4 2.5-6.3 2.5-8.7 0-7.2-7.7-21-22.4-21-22.5-6.2-6.5-6.2-17.2 0-23.7 3-3.2 7-4.9 11.3-4.9 4.3 0 8.3 1.7 11.3 4.9l1.2 1.5c0.8 1 2.4 1 3.2 0l1-1.3 0.2-0.2c3.1-3.3 7.1-5 11.3-5 4.3 0 8.3 1.7 11.3 4.9 6.2 6.5 6.2 17.2 0 23.7-0.1 0.2-13.8 14.9-21.1 22.6z"></path></g></svg>
```

embedded in an Aura component (with id [according to this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227124/custom-icons-from-static-resource-on-lightningicon-not-working))

```
<aura:component ..>
   <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
     <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade slds-p-around_small">
     <lightning:icon src="{! $Resource.myicon_svg + '#requiredId' }" />
```

doesn't display in the icon div but way outside the visble bounding box as this screenshot shows:

[image]

Why?!

Comment: It *looks* like something's wrong with SLDS? Can you include some of the surrounding code for context?

Comment: I added some elements and checked that there is no css involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this to work. Your SVG should look more like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" display="none">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 100 100" id="requiredId">
        <path fill="#f44" d="m54.3 74.1c-2.4 2.5-6.3 2.5-8.7 0-7.2-7.7-21-22.4-21-22.5-6.2-6.5-6.2-17.2 0-23.7 3-3.2 7-4.9 11.3-4.9 4.3 0 
                             8.3 1.7 11.3 4.9l1.2 1.5c0.8 1 2.4 1 3.2 0l1-1.3 0.2-0.2c3.1-3.3 7.1-5 11.3-5 4.3 0 8.3 1.7 11.3 4.9 6.2 6.5 6.2 
                             17.2 0 23.7-0.1 0.2-13.8 14.9-21.1 22.6z">
        </path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

This was shamelessly borrowed from the SLDS SVG image asset resource (from this [SVG file](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg) on https://lightningdesignsystem.com).

The demo for this code is as follows:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">   
    <div class="slds-section slds-is-open">
        <h3 class="slds-section__title slds-theme_shade slds-p-around_small">
            <lightning:icon src="{!$Resource.myicon_svg+'#requiredId'}" class="red-border-for-demo" />
        </h3>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

*(Red border added to demonstrate bounding box.)*

Output:

[image: I ❤ This SVG]

It also appears to work with the `size` attribute for automatic resizing, etc.

Comment: Great answer! The trick seem to be using `symbol` instead of `g`, unlike what's wrongly suggested in their doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/documentation. Also the viewBox is kept when using `symbol`