# LWC - CSS color fill for lightning:icon not working

Tags: css, lightning-web-components

I'm trying to color the utility "up" and "down" arrows that SLDS provides. I've confirmed that my CSS selector is correctly selecting the SVG icon in my browser console  $$('.down svg'), but the fill is not applying to the svg.

Any thoughts? Is there something special I need to do?

Thanks

```
#LWC component
<lightning-icon class="down" icon-name="utility:down" size="x-small"></lightning-icon>

#CSS
.up svg {
    fill : green;

}

.down svg {
    fill : red;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't affect the inner parts of a component because of CSS isolation. You can alter the background, border, etc of the lightning-icon, but you can't affect the arrow within aside from any supported variants. See [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/fuTKZc8-1/1/edit):

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Up Arrow</h1>
        <lightning-icon class="green-background" icon-name="utility:up" alternative-text="Up arrow" variant="inverse" size="small"></lightning-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Down Arrow</h1>
        <lightning-icon class="red-background" icon-name="utility:down" alternative-text="Down arrow" variant="inverse" size="small"></lightning-icon>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
.row{
    margin:10px 0 10px;
}
.green-background {
    background: green;
}
.red-background {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox - I worked out your example. I did come across an alternative route that told me to load a custom .css into static resources and utilize the loadStyle from the platformResourceLoader module, which worked for me. Do you know if they plan on addressing this? If not, and this is done on purpose is there a section you can refer me to on the LWC guide that talks about this "isolation" more?

Comment: @Jay It shouldn't work if the parent loads CSS, sounds like a bug. See [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_dom) "*CSS styles defined in a parent component don’t leak into a child. In our example, a  p style defined in the todoApp.css style sheet doesn’t style the p element in the c-todo-item component, because the styles don’t reach into the shadow tree.*" Also see the related docs from there.

Comment: That is interesting @sfdcfox - I took the same css and loaded it as a static resource and then just added the following to my component and it is working. renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, css + '/'),
        ])
    }

Comment: @Jay Also, where did you find that? I'd like to take a look at it, and probably check with a few people to see if it is meant to be supported this way. It's my understanding that isolation *should* be preventing this from happening.

Comment: Refer to "pdebaty" response on this post, this is what gave me the idea to try- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246887/target-inner-elements-of-standard-lightning-web-components-with-css

Comment: @Jay Thanks, I didn't see that answer. I think it'd probably be better to write your own SVG files for now and use them directly, rather than depending on behavior that I suspect is a bug. That said, let me ask about it and get back to you on it.

Comment: @sfdxfox (sorry can't chat yet - not enough rep, yet) - So, are you saying that I could create my own SVGs, import them as static resources and then just utilize the SVG tag directly in my LWC template? However, with that approach it would be one static resource per SVG, correct? I cannot create a library of SVGs, zip them up and reference them because the component javascript references the resource by a distinct individual URL, darn.

Comment: @Jay You can use multiple SVGs in a single resource, no zipping required. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/262537) I wrote on how to do that.

Comment: @sfdcfox I dont think that this is a bug. There is a kind of missunderstanding based on some unclear communication by sfdc. While they are talking always about shadow dom they don`t really serve it - but a custom one created by them (called synthetic-shadow). All the Isolation in place is therefore custom with adding scope attributes to the component css file during compilation / serving. with the real shadow dom you would be right - that would not work. In the case of platformloader they are just adding a link tag to the head. As there is no shadow dom encapsulation it just works as global

Comment: @Renji-xD Yes, but as I understand it, they do intend to switch to native Shadow DOM once IE 11 support is gone for good. If one relies on a "workaround" there is some chance it will not work in the future. I love workarounds as well as the next person, but in this case, I still maintain it is a bad idea to depend on the current behavior instead of what the documentation says about how it should work. Until/unless there's an official doc that says we're allowed to do so, I can't condone using such a workaround.

Comment: @sfdcfox ya that was just meant as explanation for people who are interested why it is currently working that way :)

Definitively agree with you that it should be used as per design even if workarounds exists which would bypass it

Answer (score 3):

1. Add a class to the lightning icon

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:down" class="svgWhite"></lightning-icon>
```

2. Add the css and change the styling hook variable
   In this case the icon was using this to display the colour

[image]

```
.svgWhite {
    --sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: white;
}
```

3. Done,

More on styling hooks here:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of your utility icon, if found the following to work.

CSS

```
 .menu-icon {
    --lwc-colorTextIconDefault: white;
  }
```

HTML

```
<lightning-icon
        icon-name="utility:connected_apps"
        alternative-text="Connected"
        title="Connected"
        class="menu-icon"
      >
      </lightning-icon>
```