# Is this a problem with the salesforce lint tool?

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-lint-tool

I can't push this lightning web component to my environment because its showing an error with the markup but I can't seem to get around it. Is there a workaround for this or just an issue that needs raising with the Salesforce guys?

I've also tried linearGradient and lineargradient as the tag name, both have the same problem

[image]

```
<template>
    <svg height="70" width="295">
        <defs>
            <lineargradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
                <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgba(54, 173, 114, 0.80);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                <stop offset="25%" style="stop-color:rgba(49, 123, 125, 0.80);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgba(44, 70, 137, 0.80);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:rgba(66, 54, 138, 0.80);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
                <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgba(98, 49, 136, 0.80);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
            </lineargradient>
        </defs>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Could you please [edit] your question and include the code as text? This would help us diagnose the problem faster. Use the `{}` button in the editor to format the code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post

Answer (score 3):

In LWC, component names are written in "kebob-case". This means that a capital letter is converted to a lowercase letter and prefixed with a hyphen. As such, `linearGradient` becomes `linear-gradient`, and this is the way it should be referenced. However, this causes a different error to appear:

> LWC1049: Forbidden svg namespace tag found in template: `<linear-gradient>` tag is not allowed within `<svg>`

It appears that, at least for v45.0, we can't use this element. You might try using an SVG resource, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/262537).

Comment: OK looks like I would need to add it as a resource and reference it that way. I might just switch back over to using HTML rather than SVG